# Silverman Proposition 2.5 computation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, elliptic-curves

In the proof of Proposition 2.5 in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, the author defines a map $$E_{ns} \to \overline{K}^*, \quad [X,Y,Z] \mapsto 1 + \frac{AX}{Y},$$ where $E_{ns}$ is the nonsingular part of the curve $$E : Y^2 Z + A XYZ - X^3 = 0.$$ He then makes the coordinate change $$X = A^2 X' - A^2 Y', \quad Y = A^3 Y', \quad Z = Z'$$ (and divides by an $A^6$ and drops the primes) to get $$E : XYZ - (X - Y)^3 = 0.$$ The author then dehomogenizes by setting $Y = 1$, giving $E : xz - (x - 1)^3 = 0$, where $x = X / Y$ and $z = Z / Y$, and says that the map above is now given by $$E_{ns} \to \overline{K}^*, \quad (x,z) \mapsto x.$$ **I don't see how the map in this new coordinate system is given by explicitly by what is written above.**

My attempt to find the map was to start in the coordinate system given by $X', Y', Z'$, then apply the inverse of the original change of coordinates to get back to the system $X, Y, Z$, then apply the original map. My thought is that the composition should be how to write the map explicitly in the new coordinates, but when I do that, I get $[X', Y', Z'] \mapsto (1 + A) + A^2 \frac{X'}{Y'}$, which would be $(x,z) \mapsto (1 + A) + A^2 x$ in the dehomogenized coordinates.

**Edit**: On the off-chance someone reads this in the future, the mistake I made above is thinking of the coordinate change in the wrong direction. The coordinate transformation from $[X',Y',Z']$ to $[X,Y,Z]$ is $[X',Y',Z'] \mapsto [A^2 X' - A^2 Y', A^3 Y', Z']$. So the accepted answer is in fact what you get when you compose the transformation with the original map to $\overline{K}^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearer when you write the new equation as
$$E : X'Y'Z' - (X' - Y')^3 = 0.$$

The map in the old coordinates is given by
$$[X,Y,Z] \mapsto 1+ \frac{AX}{Y}.$$
And in the new coordinates, you just need to replace $X, Y, Z$ by their values so
$$[X',Y',Z'] \mapsto 1 + \frac{AX([X',Y',Z'])}{AY([X',Y',Z'])} \mapsto 1+ \frac{A(A^2 X' -A^2 Y' )}{A^3 Y'} = 1+ \frac{X'}{Y'}- 1 = \frac{X'}{Y'}.$$

When you dehomogenize $x = X'/Y'.$

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: You're welcome :)